# ConcurrentDict doesnt prevent items to be null inside an loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, mmo

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, Character> kvp in World.AllChars)
{
    Character Charr = kvp.Value;
    Charr.Do(); <-- NullrefException: Charr is null
}
```

Code with the check:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, Character> kvp in World.AllChars)
{
    Character Charr = kvp.Value;
    if(Charr != null)
    {
       Charr.Do(); <-- NullrefException: Charr is null
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Nothing inside Do() causes it to be null, as it doesnt even get to execute Do() because Charr is null.

Thats how my loop looks like. I already tried to do a if != null check but it still goes past that and throws an nullref exception.

How can I prevent that? Im using a Concurrent Dictionary and a highly multithreaded server architecture.

Comment: What exactly is null? Did you look in a debugger?

Comment: Can you post the code for your null check?

Comment: You need to show us the null check code that is failing

Comment: We don't have nearly enough context here. Yes, the values within a concurrent dictionary can be null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a null check for Charr added and still get a null reference exception something in the `Do()` Method will cause this exception. Check the call stack of the exception or/and use a debugger to go through your code step by step.

Comment: No, as I said, Charr itselfe is null. I checked it on debug (mouse over charr - shows null)

Comment: I don't see a way how Charr can get null as it is a stack variable that is not influenced by other threads. But if you have it as a member variable it could of course be changed by other threads, and no concurrent list will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

The question mentions that you check for `null` but it's unclear on which value you are doing it.  Consider the following code

```
Character Charr = kvp.Value;
if (Charr != null) { 
  Charr.Do();
}
```

It is not possible in this scenario for `Char` to be `null`.  It's possible that a member of `Charr` is `null` and hence the `Do` method throws.  If that is the case though it's likely that `Character` type is not suitable for multi-threaded scenarios (at least the way they are being used)

Comment: Haha Indeed, thats how I did it when I said I checked if its null. It still happens to be null some times!

Comment: @Yuki thats not really possible barring a bug in the CLR itself.